# Min-width and max-height for table attributes

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and I want to define the `min-width` and `max-height` properties. See example below.

My problem now is that the browser doesn't take it. If I define it on `td` it gets ignored, if I define it in an `div` element inside a `td` element, the content has the right min and max width, but the table still has the same size. (so there is a lot of free space :/)

How can I resolve this?

EDIT:
I just noticed that the problem seems to only occur when the table is in fullscreen mode. Nevertheless, an element shouldn't have more than the max-width than!

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        html,body,.fullheight {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .minfield {
            max-width: 10px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
    <table class="fullheight">
        <tr>
            <td class="minfield">
                <div class="minfield">
                    <p>hallo</p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td><p>welt</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For table cells the 'width' property should be used, as the 'min-width' and 'max-width' is undefined for table cells. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths):

"In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-width' and 'max-width' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table columns, and column groups is undefined."

To enforce the width, you may try to change the [table-layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#propdef-table-layout) property to "fixed". The specification describes the algorithm pretty clearly.

Comment: thanks :/ I guess... simple task, but not possible with CSS :(, maybe someone postes a solution :)

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible with CSS? If I change the 'min-width' to 'width' in your code, the first column is very thin, and the second is wide. What does not work in your case? Note that the 'width' should be applied to 'td' while 'max-width' is still perfectly correct with 'div'.

Comment: Tell us how do you want it to work, and I believe the solution will be found. Maybe provide some more details or examples on how do you want the rendering to look.

Comment: I have a layout, which takes 1/3 of the screen-width and has a minimum witdh of 500 and a maximum width of 700. Beside it, there is another item which takes the rest of the screen. If I just assigne a width of 66% it works fine as long as the heith of the other item doesn't take one of the maximums, at which point an overflow happens or the item just lets space out. (But this acutall has nothing to do with the original question anymore because the min, max width issue was resolved by divs!)

Comment: I asked the new form under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435695/html-fullscreenlayout-with-min-width-max-width

Comment: The "width" doesn't work on cells unless you have a fixed-width table - which is ugly for many cases.  The "min-width" has some effect on non-fixed-width tables, but is not consistent - does not "obey" what you set.  We need a "width-forced" setting, since what exists seems to be broken since inception.

Answer (score 9):

To force min-height attribute for td you also can put invisible image in td, or wrap you td into div.
Example for first case:

```
<td><img style="float:left;min-height:50px;visibility:hidden;width:0px;">12345</td>
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, to get cells in a variable-width table to respect a min-width value.  Thanks so much for this.