# Mixing a few position:fixed Div's

Tags: html, css

Here is the html & css problem I'm trying to [solve](http://jsfiddle.net/z8L2oboa/):

HTML & CSS:

```css
#fixedLeftMenu {   
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 25px;
    position: fixed;    
}

#container {  
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: orange;
    width: calc(100% - 25px);
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#redFixedDiv {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;  
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;                       
}
#blueDiv {
    float: right;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: blue;   
    width: calc(100% - 25%);
}
```

```html
<div id="fixedLeftMenu"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="redFixedDiv">
    </div>
    <div id="blueDiv"></div>
</div>
```

- The **yellow div** is a *fixed* div with a fixed *width*.
- The **red div** is a *fixed* div but % *width*.
- The **blue is** % *width*;

You can see that the red and blue div's DO NOT match 100% width (the orange div container) as excepted.
The red div is being over the blue one.

If I remove the fixed position of the red, everything will be OK, but I do want it to be fixed. It maybe complex html, but I really trying to solve it. Is it possible? What I'm missing here that causes that html/css behavior?

Comment: width: calc(100% - 26%); too may work for #blueDiv

Comment: Try to resize the page and you will see the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an element with a fixed position doesn't look at its parents width when it's given a percentage width, you will need to adjust the width in the calc, so that it has accounted for the 25px margin. What I've done to the code below is first get the `pagewidth - 25px`, then divide it by 4 to get 25%

```
#redFixedDiv{
    height: 100px; background-color: red;  
    width: calc((100% - 25px) / 4);
    position: fixed;                       
}
```

Comment: Your solution has really solved it, with no horizontal scroll. I also think calc() is fine to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [fix](http://jsfiddle.net/z8L2oboa/1/) for your problem.

```
#fixedLeftMenu {   
    display:inline-block;height: 50px;background-color:yellow;
    width: 25px;
    position: fixed;    
}

#container {  
    display:inline-block; background-color:orange;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#redFixedDiv {
    height: 100px; background-color: red;  
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;                       
}
#blueDiv {
    float:right;height: 1000px;background-color: blue;   
    width: 75%;
}
```

Its not the problem of `position:fixed`. Just avoid `calc` function. That too like calc(100% - 25px). I'm not sure how browser is calculating, but your code should not depend on it, I feel. Developer/Designer should design all the components width/height/position manually, so everything works out well.

Comment: What about the overflow-x (scroller) that now appears? It means the 100% is more than the real page size. I'm trying to avoid any horizontal scroller.

Comment: Oh use 99%. Thats why you will see in most of the code 99%. just google 99% width or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435695/html-fullscreenlayout-with-min-width-max-width  or use the solution provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space

Comment: I must say that not only is calc() fine, since it is supported by all major browsers. Using 99% just to make the content fit is a very, very, very nasty hack to make your page fit