# Opera ignores height / max-height attribute

Tags: php, css, web, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Min-width and max-height for table atrributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426779/min-width-and-max-height-for-table-atrributes)

I've set a height in my css

```
.entry, p{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 2px;
font-size: 13pt;
margin: 0px;
}
.entry{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #3c3838;
    width: auto;
    margin: 5px; 
    height: 52px;
    max-height: 52px;
    display: table;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

but sadly, Opera ignores my fixed height and makes it larger as seen here

[image]

Ideas? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this answer, I think this will solve the problem for you.
[Min-width and max-height for table attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426779/min-width-and-max-height-for-table-atrributes)

and the max-height of W3 instead of the max-width defined in that answer.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-max-height

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables, inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

Comment: Unluckily, no. I've changed the height attribute in <p> to 52px as well and that seems to work, but it screws up my formatting and seems not very well or clear :)

Comment: Hmm, weird. Do you have it online? Maybe you can figure it out with the Element inspector of Firefox/chrome. It will also show you the calculated heights, so maybe you can figure it out that way.

Comment: Found a workaround, just changed the design a bit. Anyway, Score for you!