# Min-width and max-width for <td>

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Min-width and max-height for table atrributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426779/min-width-and-max-height-for-table-atrributes)

The `<tables>` and `<td>` do not understand the attributes `min-width` or `max-width` according to specification in %. How to emulate?

Comment: There is no need to make your entire question bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css3 flexbox and add css min-width and max-width.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes