# Table cell constraints

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a simple table with address and id:

```css
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
}
.id-col {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="id-col">id</th>
    <th class="address-col">Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1934</td>
    <td>Fieldstone Drive North Miami Beach, FL 33160</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>Grove Street Macon, GA 31204</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, content in `id` column can overflow its table cell.
I tried to fix it with min-width, but [it seems not to work for tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426779/min-width-and-max-height-for-table-attributes).

I solved it with flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/bkn37qtt/
Now it works as expected, but I am not sure that is good because I lost table semantics.

Is there a way to do it with table? Maybe I missed something, or anything changed since 2011 (when mentioned above question was asked)?

Comment: I can't remove `table-layout:fixed`, because otherwise table will overflow its container and would cause horizontal scroll sometimes.

Comment: You can still use flexbox but keep the table markup right ?
https://jsfiddle.net/bkn37qtt/2/

Comment: @MirkoGuarnier, yes that is one of the possible options. Do you know any caveats that I will find further if I would bet on it?

Comment: it is considered quite stable nowadays. depending on the desired browser support there are polyfills http://html5please.com/#flexbox

Comment: Ok, thanks. It looks weird for me, but I gonna try.

Comment: If you are going to use flex, then don't use table element, use div.

Comment: Yes. Also, if I do it with div, I can wrap table-rows in `a` and make them clickable without extra javascript

Comment: yepp, you can do that

Comment: .. and as you do have a flex of your own, use that, it is good as is.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! But I don't know which one I should pick as correct, since I come up with the flexbox solution.

Comment: Add your flex as a self answer and pick that one.

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the `table-layout: fixed;` and your are good to go.

Here I shortened column names as well, to make an empty content column smallest possible.

For users with bigger screen and where you can set wider table, you can add a media query to interact with an inner element of each header and set it to a fixed width, overflow hidden and ellipsis.

That will avoid the unwanted scroll to its maximum without the need of a fixed table.

```css
.scroll-container {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
table, tr, td, th {
  padding: 0;        /* remove padding/margin to make cells smallest possible */
  margin: 0;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
  max-width: 300px;
}
.id-col {
  width: 10%;
  /*min-width: 40px;    removed this as well to make it smallest possible *
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th class="id-col">id</th>
    <th class="address-col">Address</th>
    <th>Col3</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
    <th>Col5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1934</td>
    <td>Fieldstone Drive North Miami Beach, FL 33160</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>Grove Street Macon, GA 31204</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't drop it because it is necessary for some reason. I don't want horizontal scroll, but table cause it sometimes

Comment: @just-boris You can drop it, as using `table-layout: fixed;` means _Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths._ and you can read more about it here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: @just-boris Show me how the table overflow cause scroll and I fix that for you, as the above answer is how to do what you ask.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/8jg8msw0/ The thing is my real example has more columns rather than my initial question.

Comment: @just-boris I assume you want all content visible, right?, so where do you want the scroll to appear when content doesn't fit the width?

Comment: In that case, I am able to add ellipsis to column headers. As I understand, my table is aligned by header content width. Can I say to table that header size doesn't matter for me?

Comment: @just-boris Your table/cell size is content based, header also, so you can't say to header to shrink if empty content, and if setting a max-width to header will clip content too. So if this is what you want you need a script to check if there is content and set header accordingly. ... If not script is an option, I updated my answer and took out any padding and shortened header text in a way you might could too, to make a column smallest possible when no content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99298/discussion-between-just-boris-and-lgson).

Comment: @just-boris Updated my answer with something that might be interested, still, what you suggested in the chat will work good as well.

Comment: To summarize our discussion, I'd say that I have chosen to use `table`, but override display to `flexbox`: https://jsfiddle.net/8jg8msw0/4/ It doesn't do any predictions for column widths, just follows my rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<html>
<style>
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
width: 300px;
}
.id-col {
width: 10%;
min-width: 40px;
}
</style>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="id-col"><span>id</span></th>
        <th class="address-col">Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1934</td>
        <td>Fieldstone Drive North Miami Beach, FL 33160</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Grove Street Macon, GA 31204</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, You do not need fixed layout for table because ideally the table behaviour is the release the available space to the next available cell. Also you just need to get rid of any of these classes which you have added to TH to control width. Because think about a scenario when you have bigger text without spaces. It will screw design. Hence I have made changes to your codes to be more responsive.

**CSS:**

```
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table {
 width: 300px;
}
table tr>th:first-of-type,table tr>td:first-of-type{
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width:80px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th >id</th>
    <th >Address</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1984</td>
    <td>Fieldstone Drive North Miami Beach, FL 33160</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>Grove Street Macon, GA 31204</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123218736218736</td>
    <td>Fieldstone Drive North Miami Beach, FL 33160</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/e3hqyphy/)**

Cheers,

Ashok

Comment: That's good, but doesn't work for me, because my real code appeared to be more complex. See comments to @LGSon's answer, I attached a fiddle there.

Comment: Hi, The best we can do is to force overflow words in new line.Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/8jg8msw0/3/

Comment: I prefer ellipsis for it: https://jsfiddle.net/8jg8msw0/1/ But it works only for fixed tables.

Comment: It is finally your decision but ellipsis may hide some meaningful texts sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussions, I came up with the solution that flexboxes properly solves my issue

- I need to specify proportional sizes of columns
- I don't want columns to grow and overflow container (Tables without `table-layout: fixed` do it sometimes)
- I don't care about fit table head content. It is okay for me to add ellipsis
- I want to set minimal size for each column to prevent collapsing cell content

The markup on divs with `display: flex` solves this issues better, so if you have a similar issue with my, use flexboxes for it.

Here is my final version: https://jsfiddle.net/8jg8msw0/5/

**P.S.** Also it worth to note that you have to specify size for each row. With table, it is enough just set it on header.

Answer (score -1):

My Modification:

Use padding
 
Use Colgroup 
 
Increase id-col percentage 
and finally remove table-layout

```css
      table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding:2px;
      }
      table {
        /*table-layout: fixed;*/
        width: 300px;
      }
      .id-col {
        width: 15%;
        min-width: 40px;
      }
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
      <col class="con1" style="align: center; width: 15%" />
      <col class="con1" style="align: center; width: 80%" />    
    </colgroup>
    <thead>      
      <tr>
        <th class="id-col">id</th>
        <th class="address-col">Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>    
      <tr>
        <td>1934</td>
        <td>Fieldstone Drive North Miami Beach, FL 33160</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Grove Street Macon, GA 31204</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, see screenshot: https://yadi.sk/i/t8Caw7nFmbSbb Is it expected?

Comment: This won't work. You fixed it by increasing width. I can't do it on my project. I have more columns rather than I shown