# HTML Responsive table

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I want to create a responsive HTML table that increases and decreases according to certain values that I want.
The table consists of a **table header** and the **body of the table**, where I will apply more data from VUE3 (but this is not so important).

I have designed a sketch to give you an idea of what I want. Values are symbolic.
I can't apply **min-width** / **max-width** for the cells in the table.

[image]

Comment: If you will use HTML <table> than you should know, that min-width and max-width properties do not work the way you expect for <td>: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-widths

More simple way - use <div> but It is semantically incorrect to simulate data tables with <div>'s

Comment: What exactly do you want us to tell you? Where exactly is your problem? Is it that you can't apply min/max values to your cells? That's because this just isn't possible in CSS. More about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426779/min-width-and-max-height-for-table-attributes)

Comment: I want to make the table fluid. At lower resolution some of the columns to have 30px width and the same columns at higher resolution to have a maximum of 80px. And for the content inside of cells to have overflow-x-auto in case that the content will be bigger.

Comment: What's the relevant HTML to reproduce the table you've shown a picture of?